# Save the whole PHP file to another one with $_POST variables

Tags: php, post

For example, I have a simple form with POST target to PHP file:

```
<form action="language_foo.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="fname" />
<input type="text" name="age" />
<input type="Submit" name="Submit">
</form>
```

In language_foo file, I have:

```
$lang = "$_lang['item.desc']" = $_POST['fname'];
```

How can I save the user input with exact the same structure, e.g:

```
$lang = "$_lang['item.desc']" = "Jane";
```

To another PHP file? I can do file_put_contents, but it will only put "Jane" to file. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Why on *earth* would you want to do this? What’s the problem you’re trying to solve, because this doesn’t seem like a good idea.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. What is `$_lang`? Are you trying to save it as plain text -- if so, why aren't you escaping it? Better yet: what **exactly** are you trying to do?

Comment: The thing is, I want to make some kind of translation system in MODX. The PHP above is example of creating lexicons for the site. "$_lang['item.desc']" = 'Jane'; defined with different languages will output a correct string for needed language. So, the idea is, give a translation to another person. This person opens a page, filling out the inputs with translated text, hits the "Save" button, and the new, translated file with, for example $_lang['item.desc'] = 'John'; created in the right directory, so he can view the changes by himself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply `file_put_contents` the below variable `$variable_to_put_in_file`

```
$variable_to_put_in_file = '$lang = "$_lang[\'item.desc\']" = "' . $_POST['fname'] . '";';
```

Comment: Server-side code execution vulnerability.. bad idea.

Comment: Agreed. I am not really sure what the poster is trying to do, but it does solve his issue.

Comment: Thanks! This solves the problem. About the server-side code: Yes, this is bad idea, I know, but for this reason, all work will be done on developers server with appropriate access permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [`serialize()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php/) ? After filling your `$_lang` array, you can serialize the whole array to a string and dump it into a file by doing `file_put_contents(..., serialize($_lang))`, and load it back later with `$_lang = unserialize(file_get_contents(...))`.